# Bluetooth Thermal Printer language support

Tags: android

I am using a Bluetooth thermal printer for printing Bill with Android mobile application, The data which I am giving to printer is indian languages such as Hindi,Telugu,Kannada etc.. After printing, print is garbage values

Comment: When a Thermal receipt printer won't stop printing garbage, there are two things to try:

1. Perform a Power-cycle + Feed ,2. Perform an Open-Close-Feed https://help.securecdp.com/hc/en-us/articles/209426517-Thermal-receipt-printer-won-t-stop-printing-garbage

Comment: Mainy its not printing Other than English language

Comment: did you  solve this problem?

Comment: Nagaraj, Please specify the printer you are using, then we can check whether it supports Indian languages. Please note that you can check its language support by holding the Feed button the switch on the printer.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the printers are not support Indian languages.
Please note that you can check its language support by holding the Feed button the switch on the printer.